# nRF24L01+ not working by software SPI

Tags: pic, spi, nrf24l01

I want to send and receive data on the air using a pair of nRF24L01+ modules. I am using PIC16F684 as the micro-controller and working with software SPI. I put data to MOSI line before raising the SCK and read data from MISO line between raising and falling SCK (at the top). But the devices do not work. This is my code in mikroC:

```
char nRF_SPI_Read() {
  char k, d;
  d = 0;
  for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {  
    d <<= 1;
    nRF_SCK = 0b1;
    Delay_ms(1);
    if (nRF_MISO) d |= 1;
    nRF_SCK = 0b0;
    Delay_ms(1);
  }
  return d;
}

void nRF_SPI_Write(char dt) {
  char k;
  for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
    nRF_MOSI = dt.B7;
    dt <<= 1;  
    Delay_ms(1);
    nRF_SCK = 0b1;
    Delay_ms(2);
    nRF_SCK = 0b0;
    Delay_ms(1);
  }
}

void nRF_CSN_Low() {
  nRF_CSN = 0b0;
  Delay_ms(1);
}

void nRF_CSN_High() {
  nRF_CSN = 0b1;
  Delay_ms(1);
}

void nRF_WriteRegister(char reg, char val) {
  nRF_CSN_Low();
  nRF_SPI_Write(nRF_W_REGISTER | reg);
  nRF_SPI_Write(val);
  nRF_CSN_High();
}

char nRF_ReadRegister(char reg) {
  char r;
  nRF_CSN_Low();
  nRF_SPI_Write(nRF_R_REGISTER | reg);
  r = nRF_SPI_Read();
  nRF_CSN_High();
  return r;
}

void nRF_Command(char cmd) {
  nRF_CSN_Low();
  nRF_SPI_Write(cmd);
  nRF_CSN_High();
}

char nRF_Status() {
  return nRF_ReadRegister(nRF_STATUS);
}

void nRF_Clear_Status() {
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_STATUS, 0x70);
}

void nRF_FlushTXRX() {
  nRF_Clear_Status();
  nRF_Command(nRF_FLUSH_TX);
  nRF_Command(nRF_FLUSH_RX);
}

void nRF_ReadPayload() {
  char k;
  nRF_CSN_Low();
  nRF_SPI_Write(nRF_R_RX_PAYLOAD);
  for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) PayLoad[k] = nRF_SPI_Read();
  nRF_CSN_High();
}

void nRF_WritePayload() {
  char k;
  nRF_FlushTXRX();
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_CONFIG, nRF_CONFIG_MASK_TX_DS | nRF_CONFIG_MASK_MAX_RT | nRF_CONFIG_EN_CRC | nRF_CONFIG_PWR_UP);
  nRF_CSN_Low();
  nRF_SPI_Write(nRF_W_TX_PAYLOAD);
  for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) nRF_SPI_Write(PayLoad[k]);
  nRF_CSN_High();
  nRF_CE = 0b1;
  Delay_us(60);
  nRF_CE = 0b0;
}

void nRF_Init() {
  nRF_CE = 0b0;
  nRF_CSN_High();
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_CONFIG, nRF_CONFIG_MASK_TX_DS | nRF_CONFIG_MASK_MAX_RT | nRF_CONFIG_EN_CRC);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_SETUP_RETR, nRF_SETUP_RETR_ARD_250 | nRF_SETUP_RETR_ARC_0);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_SETUP_AW, nRF_SETUP_AW_5BYTES);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_RF_SETUP, nRF_RF_SETUP_RF_DR_2000 | nRF_RF_SETUP_RF_PWR_0);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_RF_CH, 9);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_EN_AA, nRF_EN_AA_NONE);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_RX_PW_P0, 2);
  nRF_WriteRegister(nRF_CONFIG, nRF_CONFIG_MASK_TX_DS | nRF_CONFIG_MASK_MAX_RT | nRF_CONFIG_EN_CRC | nRF_CONFIG_PWR_UP | nRF_CONFIG_PRIM_RX);
  //set_TX_RX_address(address, 5, TX_ADDR_reg);
  //set_TX_RX_address(address, 5, RX_ADDR_P0_reg);
  nRF_FlushTXRX();
  nRF_CE = 0b1;
}

void main() {
  bit b1, b2;

  PORTA = 0;
  PORTC = 0;
  OPTION_REG = 0b01011111;
  ANSEL = 0;
  CMCON0 = 7;
  TRISA = 0b110000;
  WPUA = 0b110000;
  TRISC = 0b100001;

  b1 = RA5_bit;
  b2 = RA4_bit;
  PayLoad[0] = 0; 
  nRF_Init();
  while (1) {
    if (b1 != RA5_bit) {
      Delay_ms(500); // debouncing
      if (b1) {
        PayLoad[0] = 45; 
        PayLoad[1] = 84;
        RA0_bit = !RA0_bit;
      }
      b1 = RA5_bit;
    }
    if (b2 != RA4_bit) {
      Delay_ms(500); // debouncing
      if (b2) {
        PayLoad[0] = 108; 
        PayLoad[1] = 240; 
        RA1_bit = !RA1_bit;
      }
      b2 = RA4_bit;
    }
    if (PayLoad[0]) { 
      nRF_WritePayload(); 
      PayLoad[0] = 0; 
    }
    if (nRF_Status().B6) {
      nrf_ReadPayload(); // RX_Payload(&dt);
      if ((PayLoad[0] == 45) && (PayLoad[1] == 84)) RA0_bit = !RA0_bit;
      if ((PayLoad[0] == 108) && (PayLoad[1] == 240)) RA1_bit = !RA1_bit;
      PayLoad[0] = 0;
      nRF_Clear_Status();
    }
    Delay_100ms();
  }
}
```

And this is pins state on logic analyzer for `nRF_Status()` function:
[image]
What are the signals I circled them by pink color? My micro does not read them. Why the first byte and second byte that is read from nRF are not same? (both of them must be the value of status register, am I right?). Why no data transmitted between two devices?

Comment: How did you capture this waveform? Why are you not using the rising or falling edge of the SCLK to sample? Perhaps that is why the circled data is not getting sampled, they are line up with the falling and rising edges of SCLK.

Comment: just a note: 07FF is not reading the status register. It's just 0xff, being a standalone command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved. There is nothing wrong with the code. I just added a 100uF capacitor on nRF power. It seems there is something with nRF power consumption!

Answer (score 0):

Outgoing data changes normally when the clock falls and ditto data sent from a slave: -

[image]

This means you read-in MISO data on the rising edge of the master clock.

Comment: According to datasheet, data is valid 55ns after falling edge, so i sampled it a little after raising clock signal.

Comment: Well if you have long tracks across the PCB this timing figure may become a little stretched but providing you sample between the rising edge and before the next falling edge you should be OK